# Is there a way to include and execute a Python script and render the output in MkDocs using markdown-exec?

Tags: python, documentation, mkdocs

As I am building [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) documentation pages I have integrated many python scripts within. This is possible by using [markdown-exec](https://pypi.org/project/markdown-exec/) syntax:

````
```python exec="on"
print("Hello Markdown!")
````

However it is very cumbersome and annoying to work with Python code inside markdown (`.md`) pages as I am unable to test or auto-format code blocks on the fly. It makes documentation pretty clunky to construct. Extracting code from markdown into their own Python (`.py`) files would make everything easier to maintain, documentation more consistent, help with dynamics, and reduce git diffs.

I already tried playing around with markdown-exec syntax to enable loading external Python files, but I haven't been successful in completing that task so far. markdown-exec doesn't mention anything inside their documentation pages about loading external sources and their examples only show inline code. I even tried using a combination of markdown-exec and [snippets](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/), however snippets don't resolve before markdown-exec compiles the code.

Ultimately it would be easiest if there was a way to load python code snippets into mkdocs before markdown-exec compiles and runs the code.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this myself by getting rid of all snippets plugins and using the following config:

```
markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.snippets:
      check_paths: true
      base_path: [docs/snippets, "."]
```

And then here the correct md page content to load `script.py`:

````
```python exec="true" source="tabbed-right"
--8<-- "docs/snippets/script.py"
```
````